# How to enable Bootstrap css in only WooCommerce Checkout Page

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, woocommerce

I have WordPress woocommerce theme. I want to make my checkout page more beautiful.

I want to enable Bootstrap css and js in my checkout only. In my checkout page I have Form Fields + Select Box etc.

Please help me in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

There is lots of information missing in order to give you the correct answer.
Need to see how you have laid out your code.

The most simple answer would be:

If you have created a separate HTML file for your checkoutPage. 
Make sure you have it enabled in your 'head' section
You can either
A: Download the bootstrap package from this URL here
https://getbootstrap.com/
If you choose to download the package you will have to unzip the downloaded file and place the appropriate files for the 'css' and 'js' of bootstrap into your Folder that contains your code but make sure you place your css files in your css folder and js files into your js folder and so on.
or 
B: you can simply link it with the below code

```
<head>

     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
     <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
     <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
     <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>
```

Hope this helps you ...

Answer (score 0):

Where you're using WordPress, you could make use of WordPress hooks. If you have a checkout template set-up, you could reference it through that. See below for setting up the header in a template page.

Template page file names should always start with page- so you could have a template called page-checkout.php with a header of...

```
<?php
/**
 *
 ** Template Name: Checkout Page
 *
 */

get_header(); ?>
```

Then in your header.php file where you call the CSS and JS for the checkout page you could write a simple PHP if statement using WordPress hooks to only have it pull on that one page.

```
<?php

if(is_page_template('page-checkout.php') { ?>

  <style>
  </style>

  <script>
  </script>

<?php } ?>
```

You could also use is_page instead of is_page_template. Here's some more information [is_page](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_page/) and [is_page_template](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_page_template/).

```
<?php

if(is_page('checkout') { ?>

  <style>
  </style>

  <script>
  </script>

<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Simple add following CSS code and your issue will be fixed. It is working fine with me**

```
.woocommerce-billing-fields .form-row, .woocommerce-shipping-fields .form-row,.woocommerce form .form-row
{
display: block;
}

.woocommerce .col2-set .col-1, .woocommerce-page .col2-set .col-1,.woocommerce .col2-set .col-2, .woocommerce-page .col2-set .col-2 {
max-width: unset;
}
```